# Laravel: How to mark Session data as flashed

Tags: laravel, session

I am trying to pre-populate an input on a form for the creation of a model entity in Laravel 5.4. But the form is a shared blade template with the edit form for the same model, where I want to use form-model binding to provide the input.

The way I have achieved this so far is to flash a session variable to `_old_input` in the controller for the creation route:
`session()->flash('_old_input.description', $event->description);`

This achieves exactly what I want it to, with the exception of not being cleaned out at the end of the request. My next request still has the session data flashed.

My question is how does Laravel know that this is the recipient of a flash message as opposed to the input of a flashed message? And is there a way to tell it that I've already used the session flash and it should be cleaned up at the end of this request...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use redirect to flash the session... otherwise, you will end up with the flash staying on for the next request...

You can return a view... like

```
return redirect('view')->with('_old_input.description', $event->description);
```

Or you can even redirect to a controller action ... like

```
session()->flash('_old_input.description', $event->description);
return redirect()->action('MyController@function');
```

which would work also... the key is to return a redirect response...

Hope this helps...

Comment: I see I can use this, but surely it will mean that I need to have an additional route and controller to handle providing a default; I think on further inspection that you can move the session key from the `new` line of the `flash_vars` to the `old` and that will mean that it is cleared out with this request

Comment: Redirect to the edit route? Unless you want to manage it yourself but that creates a different set of problem... Flash sets up the session for the next request... if in the current request you create an ok response, that session will have this set... then when the next session comes it will be set and cleared... if you redirect from this request, you create another request/response cycle and thus only see it once in the client... Either way you must manage something... I find the redirect cleaner and expressive...

Comment: But the edit route requires me to have a model to pass in, in this case I can't create one as certain required attributes are not yet known.

Answer (score 0):

Serge is correct that flash is intended for use to put data into the session for the NEXT request and thus redirecting is the correct way to do this, I will also provide here the solution I used to hack my way past this...

Laravel stores its flash data in the `_flash` value in the session array, with keys which are to be used in the NEXT request under the `new` key, and keys which were used in THIS request in the `old` key; see extract below.

```
[_flash] => Array
    (
        [old] => Array
            (
            )

        [new] => Array
            (
                [0] => _old_input
            )
    )
```

Using `session()->push('_flash.old', '_old_input');` fools Laravel into thinking that this is data that was flashed into this request from the previous one, and clears up the data at the end of its cycle.

For full effect, you can use `session()->forget('_flash.new.0');` to remove it from the new key, although beware that this is not necessarily the first flashed var (in my case it is).

My total code is therefore:

```
session()->flash('_old_input', ['description' => $event->description]);
session()->push('_flash.old', '_old_input');
session()->forget('_flash.new.0');
```

Again, Serge is correct but if anyone else comes here to find out how Laravel's flashing works and wants to circumvent it, here is a bit of information